# How to use IntegerQ in FunctionCompile?

Tags: compile, expression-test

Seems like an easy request, but I've somehow gotten myself stuck again:

```
cf = FunctionCompile[Function[
   {Typed[list, TypeSpecifier["PackedArray"]["Real64", 1]]}, 
   Module[{Typed[func, {"Real64"} -> "Boolean"] = 
      KernelFunction[IntegerQ]},
    func /@ list]
   ]]
```

[image]

Comment: I know there’s supposed to be a way to register functions in this new compilation stuff. There might be a talk about it online?

Comment: IntegerQ always gives False for any Real64 numbers, so I don't see how that would be useful even if it worked.

Comment: @ilian you are right, I was trying to make a toy example... I’ll try to revise it. I guess I don’t know the true type of the list, just that the elements of the list are numeric

Comment: Basically I have some loop that stops when the thing is an integer

Comment: Why not just use `Mod[x, 1] == 0` as your test for an integer?

Comment: Why not use any other equivalent code?

Comment: @M.R. you might be able to make use of the type system to do type-dispatching on this. Tom Wickham Jones had some video I saw where he did exactly that for related stuff. The type system built into `FunctionCompile` does seem pretty powerful

Answer (score 5):

I think the specific syntax for [KernelFunction](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KernelFunction.html) you were looking for is this:

```
func = Typed[KernelFunction[IntegerQ], {"Real64"} -> "Boolean"]
```

But this, as Ilian pointed out, won't help you since `IntegerQ` always gives `False` for all reals.

A possible way to do this with `FunctionCompile` might be (in 12.2):

```
f = Function[{
 Typed[list, TypeSpecifier["PackedArray"]["Real64", 1]]
 }, 
 Module[{a = CreateDataStructure["DynamicArray"]},
  Do[
   a["Append", FractionalPart[list[[i]]] == 0.],
   {i, 1, Length[list]}
  ];
  Normal[a]
]]
```

And then:

```
cf = FunctionCompile[f]
```

And then:

```
cf[{1.2, 2.0, 4.5}]
```

Gives `{False, True, False}`